# Retrieve latest row of data based on a condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using my google scripts to retrieve the most recent row of data from my google sheet based on a condition. My code bellow is able to retrieve data however it selects the oldest data and not the newest.

```
function retreiveData(number){
  var url = "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1, ws.getLastRow(), ws.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  var dataValues = [];
  var find = 204; //Value I am trying to find
  var filterData = data.filter(
    function(r){
      if(r[3] == find){ //the condition is in the 4th column (column D)
        var i = 4;//begins in the 5th column (column E) 
        while(i < 55){//My spreadsheet has 55 columns
          Logger.log(r[i]);
          dataValues.push(r[i]);
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  )
  
  var k = 0;
  while(k < 51){
    Logger.log(k +  " " + dataValues[k]);
    k++;
  }

  return dataValues;
}
```

Currently returning the top row, it is not returning the newer row that I have highlighted.
[image]

Comment: Are your data rows sorted, if so, is newest at the top or at the bottom?  Is there a field that has a date or other way to know how new it is?  Also, I am not clear why you are running a loop inside a filter?

Answer (score 3):

**Getting the last selected row**

```
function retreiveData1(number=17) {
  var url = "url";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  let dvs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().filter(r => r[3] == number);
  dvs = [dvs[dvs.length - 1]];
  dsh.clear();
  dsh.getRange(1,1,dvs.length,dvs[0].length).setValues(dvs);
}
```

Test Data:

| 24 | 21 | 9 | 24 | 16 | 7 | 12 | 13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 19 | 9 | 19 | 20 | 7 | 11 | 18 |
| 19 | 18 | 6 | 1 | 19 | 16 | 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 0 | 4 | 19 | 8 | 12 | 8 | 20 |
| 19 | 19 | 8 | 24 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 18 |
| 22 | 6 | 9 | 2 | 17 | 18 | 5 | 20 |
| 22 | 13 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 15 | 24 | 14 |
| 20 | 7 | 8 | 21 | 11 | 2 | 10 | 22 |
| 4 | 11 | 12 | 21 | 13 | 6 | 9 | 22 |
| 12 | 19 | 23 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 5 | 12 |
| 3 | 18 | 11 | 17 | 7 | 12 | 3 | 22 |
| 19 | 19 | 11 | 3 | 13 | 15 | 4 | 12 |
| 23 | 1 | 10 | 16 | 20 | 11 | 5 | 20 |
| 17 | 20 | 14 | 13 | 4 | 13 | 15 | 1 |
| 8 | 4 | 22 | 8 | 13 | 19 | 24 | 3 |
| 4 | 19 | 24 | 13 | 11 | 9 | 19 | 9 |
| 3 | 3 | 14 | 7 | 1 | 6 | 24 | 16 |
| 22 | 0 | 21 | 7 | 16 | 16 | 7 | 16 |
| 2 | 20 | 16 | 17 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 5 |
| 23 | 18 | 17 | 6 | 17 | 24 | 13 | 11 |
| 16 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 22 | 4 | 20 | 6 |
| 14 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 15 | 22 | 12 | 20 |
| 4 | 6 | 3 | 5 | 20 | 12 | 11 | 11 |
| 17 | 13 | 8 | 15 | 9 | 17 | 15 | 21 |
| 0 | 15 | 19 | 3 | 4 | 14 | 16 | 20 |

Results:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20 | 16 | 17 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 5 |

This provides a simple User Interface for entering data:

```
function retreiveData3() {
  const url = "";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iUA-rv6h7y0Q562XVGWZFwzTNB-LNuHZbkS3pTmA99M/edit#gid=1280165640");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter number to find', 'Search Dialg', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let number = parseInt(r.getResponseText());
    let dvs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().filter(r => r[3] == number);
    dvs = [dvs[dvs.length - 1]];
    dsh.clear();
    if (dvs && dvs.length > 0) {
      dsh.getRange(1, 1, dvs.length, dvs[0].length).setValues(dvs);
      ss.toast(`${dvs.length}`,'Matches')
    } else {
      ss.toast('None','Matches');
    }

  } else {
    ss.toast('Process Cancelled');
  }
}
```

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20 | 16 | 17 | 10 | 7 | 4 | 5 |

This displays the  data in a dialog:

```
function retreiveData2() {
  const url = "";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iUA-rv6h7y0Q562XVGWZFwzTNB-LNuHZbkS3pTmA99M/edit#gid=1280165640");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter number to find', 'Search Dialg', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let number = parseInt(r.getResponseText());
    let dvs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().filter(r => r[3] == number);
    dvs = [dvs[dvs.length - 1]];
    if (dvs && dvs.length > 0) {
      let h = "ABCDEFGH".split("").map(e => `<th>${e}</th>`).join('');
      let html = `<style> td,th{border:1px solid black}</style><table>${h}`;
      dvs.forEach((r, i) => {
        html += '<tr>';
        r.forEach((c, j) => {
          html += `<td>${c}</td>`;
        });
        html += '</tr>';
      });
      html += '</table>';
      Logger.log(html);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Display Dialog");
      ss.toast(`${dvs.length}`, 'Matches')
    } else {
      ss.toast('None', 'Matches');
    }

  } else {
    ss.toast('Process Cancelled');
  }
}
```

Data:

[image]

The only issue with my answer is that I can't tell from you question how to determine which row is the oldest.  Rows don't have age unless you have some other definition to offer then I can't provide that functionality.

It seems that you now want the last one nearest the bottom of the sheet.

**Finding the Last Row**

```
function retreiveData() {
  const url = "";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iUA-rv6h7y0Q562XVGWZFwzTNB-LNuHZbkS3pTmA99M/edit#gid=1280165640");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter number to find', 'Search Dialg', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let number = parseInt(r.getResponseText());
    let dvs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().filter(r => r[3] == number);
    dvs = [dvs[dvs.length - 1]];//this selects the last row in an array of spreadsheet data and places it into an array so that it's two dimensional again.
    if (dvs && dvs.length > 0) {
      let h = "ABCDEFGH".split("").map(e => `<th>${e}</th>`).join('');
      let html=`<style> td,th{border:1px solid black}</style><table>${h}`;
      dvs.forEach((r,i) => {
          html += '<tr>';
        r.forEach((c,j) => {
          html+= `<td>${c}</td>`;
        });
        html += '</tr>';
      });
      html+= '</table>';
      Logger.log(html);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Display Dialog");
      ss.toast(`${dvs.length}`,'Matches')
    } else {
      ss.toast('None','Matches');
    }

  } else {
    ss.toast('Process Cancelled');
  }
}
```

Data:

[image]

Comment: I apologize, I am new. May I asked what the code means: `r => r[3] == number` I see it is connected to the range but is r any value in the range or rows or columns? because also i did not see any iterations.

Comment: if your asking about this: `filter(r => r[3] == number)` r is an element of the array and in this case is a two dimensional array so r is a row of spreadsheet and r[3] is the fourtth column in this case.  The whole thing just say to only keep those elements where value in fourth column is equal to the number.

Comment: The whole expression is done in arrow notation it could have been written as `filter(function(row){row[3] == number}` or `for(let i =0;i<Array.length;i++){return row[3]=number)`

Comment: nice. thank you.

Comment: In equation above `=` should have been `==`